# how to test code (private methods ) without a unit framework in .net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, testing, methods, private

i have taken over an application which was developed over many years from many developers and is written in vb.net. this application will be only used in-house and is running on an isolated environment.

i would like to include some tests to this application for safety-reason
to have some verification when i am changing something in the code -
and later on maybe trying to refactor it.

unfortunately i cant use any of the unit testing frameworks,
because almost all of the methods are private.
i guess "spaghetti-code" could fit here very well.

**what would be a way to include some tests into this application?**

the app is written in vb.net, but c# would also fit.

of course, i could change the methods f.e. to public.
but that's what i don't want to do here in a first step.

**and i am curious how to run tests on private or internal code parts?**

thank you in advance.

br
lakk

Comment: Would you be willing to consider something temporary, like Partial Classes?  You could make a partial class, with public pass-throughs (wrappers) for-testing-only, and omit those during prod builds.  Avoids changing the original code.

Comment: hello tgolisch. 
sure, any ideas are welcome!

Comment: You also may be able to use InternalsVisibleTo to expose the private routines to testing.  It's not something that would be recommended for new development, but might make sense for something like this.

Comment: Maybe I'm a little off on this one, my feeling is if these methods are private, the are private for a reason.  They are intended for use specifically within the context of the object they are declared private in. Therefore, for any test to be valid, it really needs to be tested in that same context.